# R - round via parameter in function

Tags: r

My dataframe look like this

```
source_df <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(seq(1: 3)),
    nr = c(1.487, 2.2749, 2.9710),
    cn = c("us", "uk", "ca")
  )
```

I have this function for select columns and it also should selected values to decimal places in parameter round_to

```
selector <- function(df, colname, round_to = 1) {
  df %>%  
    select(id, colname) %>% 
    mutate(colname = round(colname, round_to))
    rename_at(vars(-id), ~paste0('selected_', .))
}
```

If I call it this way

```
selector(source_df, c("nr"))
```

Im getting error

```
 Error in round(colname, round_to) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I guess that this is related to mutate function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of standard evaluation. To unquote variable names, use `rlang::sym` and `!!`:

```r
selector <- function(df, colname, round_to = 1) {
  df %>%  
    select(id, colname) %>% 
    mutate(colname = round(!!rlang::sym(colname), round_to)) %>%
    rename_at(vars(-id), ~paste0('selected_', .))
}
```

You can have a look at this [blog post](https://linogaliana.netlify.app/post/datatable/datatable-nse/) I wrote on the subject of unquoting variable names in `dplyr`

Comment: You just missed the pipe after the mutate selector <- function(df, colname, round_to = 1) {
  df %>%  
    select(id, colname) %>% 
    mutate(colname = round(!!rlang::sym(colname), round_to)) %>%
    rename_at(vars(-id), ~paste0('selected_', .))
}